# in python, how ensure any exceptions are logged with logger?

Tags: python, logging, stderr

In a python app, how can I ensure that anything to stderr also goes to the `logger`, so if for example if the app crashes with an untrapped exception I can see that in the log?

My current logging setup is:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_log_handler = logging.FileHandler('myapp.log')
logger.addHandler(file_log_handler)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_log_handler)
```

In the python logging docs I saw pretty much everything except how to send stderr to the logfile.

I know I can redirect stderr to a file like this:

```
sys.stderr = open('./myapp_errors.log', 'w')
```

However, I'm hoping to use `logger` to log exceptions so that (a) the formatting is consistent, and (b) I can log exceptions to the same file.

Comment: maybe you could create your own file like object, that delegates to the logger, and set `sys.stderr` equal to it? https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: If you like the answer by `univerio`, why not mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) to be your own handler. Then you can log to your own logger as you see fit:

```
import sys

def _excepthook(exctype, exc, tb):
    logger.error("An unhandled exception occurred.", exc_info=(exctype, exc, tb))

sys.excepthook = _excepthook
```

In fact, the default behavior of writing to stderr comes from the default value of `sys.excepthook`.